# Commit failed silently with Spring JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I work on a project developed by a team mate but we are facing a strange issue that drive me crazy: database is never updated and there's no exception in the logs. Here's the code:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class InterventionProjectResultIntegrator implements IInterventionProjectResultIntegrator {

  private static final ILogger logger = ComponentLogger.getInstance(InterventionProjectResultIntegrator.class);

  private Dao dao;
  private String APPLICATION = "APP";

  @Autowired
  public void setDao(Dao dao){
    this.dao = dao; 
  }

  @Override
  public void integrateResponse() {

    try {
      List<ResponseEntity> responseListByStatus = dao.findAllResponseByStatus(Dao.STATUS_EN_COURS, APPLICATION);

      for (ResponseEntity response: responseListByStatus ) {
        response.setStatus(Dao.STATUS_OK);
        dao.mergeResponseEntity(response);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the function is pretty simple:

1. Getting objects from database
2. Loop over the objects
3. Update Each object status
4. At the end of the loop commit changes

Everything run fine except that the objects are not updated on database and that there is no exception.

The Dao come from a maven dependency that worked fine in another project so I assume that the problem is related to the new one.

I can see following logs in console:

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@6dcee890] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@713e49c3] bound to thread org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener - Persistent instance of: com.domain.ResponseEntity
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener - Ignoring persistent instance
org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions - No entity insert actions have non-nullable, transient entity dependencies.
```

Did you already face similar issue ?

Regards.

**[EDIT 1]**

As pointed out in comment, I replaced manual transaction handling with *@Transactional* annotation. See the code updated.

So now I have a new line in the logs, but the same result, object is not save in database.

```
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport - Completing transaction for [com.response.InterventionProjectResultIntegrator.integrateResponse]
```

As asked the DAO source. This code is not under my responsability, and worked like a charm in another context.

```
@Repository
public class Dao {
  public static final ILogger logger = ComponentLogger.getInstance(Dao.class);

  public static final String STATUS_EN_COURS = "PENDING";
  public static final String STATUS_OK = "OK";
  public static final String STATUS_ERROR = "ERROR";

  @PersistenceContext
  protected EntityManager entityManager;

  public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  public void mergeMvzResponseEntity(ResponseEntity responseEntity) {
    if(entityManager != null) {
      this.entityManager.merge(responseEntity);
    } else {
      logger.error("Entity manager not initialized");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your dao. Also your code is flawed, in case of exception you should rollback the transaction, currently you hvae a connection leak. Also why are you even managing the transaction yourself? let spring handle it by simply making the method transactional, saves you writing tedious tx code.

Comment: @M.Deinum Here's infos you asked for. I follow your advice and decided to use Transactional annotation but don't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I have reworked the source code to use @Transactional annotation, and to let Spring handle transaction stuff:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class InterventionProjectResultIntegrator implements IInterventionProjectResultIntegrator {

  private static final ILogger logger = ComponentLogger.getInstance(InterventionProjectResultIntegrator.class);

  private Dao dao;
  private String APPLICATION = "APP";

  @Autowired
  public void setDao(Dao dao){
    this.dao = dao; 
  }

  @Override
  public void integrateResponse() {

    try {
      List<ResponseEntity> responseListByStatus = dao.findAllResponseByStatus(Dao.STATUS_EN_COURS, APPLICATION);

      for (ResponseEntity response: responseListByStatus ) {
        response.setStatus(Dao.STATUS_OK);
        dao.mergeResponseEntity(response);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      logger.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
      throw ex;
    }
  }
}
```

Then added this line to my xml configuration file:

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>
```

Now it works like a charm. Thanks to @M. Deinum to have pointed it out.